# Powershell if AD attribute not set

Tags: powershell

I have the following calculated expression:

```
@{n="Sites.short_name";e={ if (([int]$_.telephoneNumber.Substring(0,1) -gt 0) -and ([int]$_.telephoneNumber.Substring(0,1) -lt 10)) {"$($_.telephoneNumber.Substring(0,1))00"} elseif (!$_.telephoneNumber) {"LOA"} else {"LOA"} }}
```

The problem here is that for some users the `telephoneNumber` property is not set. How can I evaluate if the attribute exists and then set the value of "LOA" if the attribute doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `telephoneNumber` returns a string, you can do the following. (Expanded out over multiple lines to look clearer.

```
$SomeUser | Select-Object @{
    Label = "sites.short_name";
    Expression = {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.telephoneNumber)) { "LOA" }
        elseif ($_.telephoneNumber.Substring(0,1) -match "[1-9]") {   # satisfies condition x > 0 and x < 10
            $_.telephoneNumber.Substring(0,1) + "00"
        }
        else {
            "LOA"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be on a single line?

This would be much more readable as a function. e.g.

```
function Get-TelephonePrefix {
    param (
        [string]$TelephoneNumber
    )

    if($TelephoneNumber -match '^([0-9])') {
        return $matches[0] + '00'
    }
    return 'LOA'
}

$TestValues = @('abc', '213 11', '')
$TestValues.foreach{
    $_
    Get-TelephonePrefix -TelephoneNumber $_
}
```